# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We define $\mathbb{Z}_3=\{0,1,2\}$, the set of integers modulo $3$

Prove it is a field.

Here I have made two tables, showing the relationship by $+,\cdot$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 0 & 1\end{array}$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\cdot & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
2 & 0 & 2 & 1\end{array}$$

Read it as, $2+1=0$, since $2+1=3$, and $3\mod 3 = 0$.

I want to prove the property that any $d\in\mathbb{Z}_3$, there is $y$ such that $d\cdot y = 1$, where $d,y\in\{0,1,2\}$.

Consider all cases.

If $d=1$, let $y=1$, then $d\cdot y = 1$

If $d=2$, let $y=2$, then $d\cdot y = 1$

If $d=0$, let $y=??$, then $d\cdot y = 1$

> In the final case, no matter what we choose $y$ as, $d\cdot y$ will never be $1$. So then $0$ does not have a multiplicative identity, but my book still says this is a field. How?

Comment: Re-read the field axioms.  The additive identity doesn't have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: I see the problem thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of a field requires that the NONzero elements have inverses.

Good exercise:  prove from ring axioms alone that if $R$ is a ring with identity and $0$ is invertible, then $R=\{0\}$.  So, if you want more than one element in your field, you better not let $0$ have an inverse.

Comment: Many authors specify that the additive and multiplicative identities must be distinct elements.  But I don't think it's of much consequence if one says $\{0\}$ is(n't) a field; I'm not aware of this leading to anything controversial down the line like Axiom of Choice or some such might.

Comment: Of course it doesn't (hence the meaning of my last "if").   I do appreciate the simplicity of statements of results requiring the characteristic being either 0 or a prime, and not having to declare the annoying case of $\mathrm{char}(F)=1$.

Comment: Actually, down the line it can be rather useful for the category of rings to have a terminal element.